# Can I access the files I create with USB

Tags: android

I'm lost here.

I create files using this (stripped) code :

```
File dir = getBaseContext().getDir(dirPath, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
try {
File file = new File(dir, fileName);
FileOutputStream fous = new FileOutputStream(file);
fous.write(data);
fous.flush();
fous.close();
long l = file.length();
Log.i("PpCameraActivity", "File size : " + l);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error while trying to write photo file",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I can verify with logcat that my file seems to be created (it has a not null lenght). But I cannot see it when I connect my android device to my PC.
So... where is my file ? Is it hidden ? Erased ?

EDIT : I'm now trying to write on the SDCard specifically, using this :

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File jpegFile = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/myApplication/" + filePath);

try {
jpegFile.mkdirs();

FileOutputStream fous = new FileOutputStream(jpegFile);
fous.write(data);
fous.flush();
fous.close();
Log.i("PpCameraActivity", "File written : " + jpegFile.getAbsolutePath());
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File written : " + jpegFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
long l = jpegFile.length();
Log.i("PpCameraActivity", "File size : " + l);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error while trying to write photo file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But I get a FileNotFoundException on the FileOutputStream creation...

Comment: Maybe is it that my new dir isn't created on the sdcard ? If so how do I choose to create a dir on the sdcard ?

Comment: It seems I should be able to write files in the sdcard obtained with 
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

But when I try to write I get a FileNotFoundException...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found it.

Not an Android problem but just my error (not the first time) : mkdirs must be applied to the parent file, not the file I want to write...

So, for people interested :

Access the sd card using

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Don't forget to require this permission

```
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Then make, as usual, mkdirs and file creation.

And don't forget : the android device cannot write on the sdard while it is mounted on you PC.

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't writing to the SD card, and the SD contents are all you can see from a USB connection.

Try something like this: http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/writing-to-sd-card-in-android.html  (just the first thing that came up when I searched for "Android write to SD card").

Comment: I saw this page, but It doesn't seem easy to write here.
I get a FileNotFoundException when I try to write a file (after having made a mkdirs).